# finding all rows which are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting every tr rather then checked ones.

```
$.each($("#sample-table-1 tr.main"), function (key, value) {
    if ($(value).closest("td").find('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true))
        console.log($(value).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rather get the checked checkboxes and then get their closest parent tr:

```
$("#sample-table-1 tr.main :checked").each(function(){
   console.log($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
});
```

If row has multiple checkboxes:

```
$("#sample-table-1 tr.main").filter(function(){
    return $(this).find(':checked').length > 0;
}).each(function(){
     console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: yeah this worked but I should put something just in case if there is another checkbox in row.

Comment: I solved it like this. $("#sample-table-1 tr.main td.check :checked")

Comment: that will still log row n times if n checkboxes are checked. you should rather use filter approach.

Answer (score 0):

change `prop('checked', true)` to `prop('checked')` because `prop('checked', true)` will set the value rather than returning it

try this

```
$.each($("#sample-table-1 tr.main"), function (key, value) {
    if ($(value).find('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked'))
        console.log($(value).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this thing :

```
$.each($("#sample-table-1 tr.main"), function (key, value) {
    console.log($(value)); //this is for debugging purpose only. What does it write in console?
    if ($(value).closest("td").find('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked')===true)
         console.log($(value).attr('id'));
});
```